# Python video system not intilated

Tags: python, pygame

Here it is, I dont know what is wrong, I looked at other answers but I still dont know what is wrong?

```
import pygame

pygame.init()

gameWindow = pygame.display.set_mode((1000,600));
pygame.display.set_caption("Practice")
#game starts
gameActive = True
while gameActive:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        #print event
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            gameActive = False

    pygame.quit()
quit()
```

Answer (score 1):

You have `pygame.quit()` in your main loop, so after one iteration through the loop you are calling `pygame.quit()`, which causes pygame to no longer be initialized which creates the error of not having a display surface.

Moving `pygame.quit()` out of the main while loop fixes the issue.